# How to get user country without gps

Tags: react-native, expo

In react native i am trying to get user country without using the users gps, just like Wechat registration which automatically gets the users country in the picker(select) field.

Comment: You can geolocate the device IP addess

Comment: Or get the device country based on the current Locale.

Comment: How do you mean geolocate the device IP address, should i use an api to find the location of the gps?

Comment: Nope. I mean using a REST API like [that](https://ipgeolocation.io). Either `IP geolocation` and the `device country` are not a 100% bullet proof solution, because someone could navigate through VPN or have changed the device country. But that's not the case of a typical user. So I think that Jigar answer is the one that actual fits your needs. C'ya.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it can be done by two ways

1. get the IP address of user but it works only with internet connection
2. the best way is to get the local country of the device itself with the use of 
   `react-native-device-info`

`const deviceCountry = DeviceInfo.getDeviceCountry(); // "US", "IN"`

ref: [react-native-device-info#getdevicecountry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getdevicecountry)

Comment: I want the country to be like "India", "Russia".

Comment: `getDeviceCountry()` is deprecated

Comment: It's not supported anymore: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#readme

Answer (score 9):

**getDeviceCountry() is removed** from react-native-device-info.

Use [react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize):

```
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

RNLocalize.getCountry(); // -> 'UA'
```

If you want to get a **full country name like "United States"** then you can add following json file to your project: https://gist.github.com/ssskip/5a94bfcd2835bf1dea52

And then import and get full country name by code:

```
const countries = require('./countries.json')
// Or in ES6:
// import countries from './countries.json'

countries[RNLocalize.getCountry()] // -> 'United States'
```

Comment: RNLocalize.getCountry(); is based on user language but not based on user location.

Comment: @Milon is right. I am in India and have selected en-US as default language. But it returns country US.